# Update state from axios call in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm new to react and I've just started learning about hooks and context.

I am getting some data from an API with the following code:

```js
const getScreen = async uuid => {

    const res = await axios.get(
      `${url}/api/screen/${uuid}`
    );

    dispatch({
      type: GET_SCREEN,
      payload: res.data
    });
  };
```

Which goes on to use a reducer.

```js
case GET_SCREEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        screen: action.payload,
      };
```

In Screen.js, I am calling `getScreen` and sending the `UUID` to show the exact screen. Works great. The issue I am having is when I am trying to fetch the API (every 3 seconds for testing) and update the state of `nodeupdated` based on what it retrieves from the API. The issue is, `screen.data` is always undefined (due to it being asynchronous?)

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useContext,
} from 'react';
import SignageContext from '../../context/signage/signageContext';

const Screen = ({ match }) => {
  const signageContext = useContext(SignageContext);

  const { getScreen, screen } = signageContext;

  const [nodeupdated, setNodeupdated] = useState('null');

  const foo = async () => {
    getScreen(match.params.id);

    setTimeout(foo, 3000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    foo();
    setNodeupdated(screen.data)
  }, []);
```

If I remove the [] is does actually get the data from the api ... but in an infinate loop.

The thing is this seemed to work perfectly before I converted it to hooks:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    // Get screen from UUID in url
    this.props.getScreen(this.props.match.params.id);

    // Get screen every 30.5 seconds
    setInterval(() => {
      this.props.getScreen(this.props.match.params.id);

      this.setState({
        nodeUpdated: this.props.screen.data.changed
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
```

Comment: If you remove the `[]`, the useEffect hook will run everytime a prop is updated. I think the infinite loop is due to your setTimeout method?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom hook like `useInterval`

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Then in your component

```
 useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, delay);
```

Dan Abramov has a great blog post about this

https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this. Just replace the console.log with your API request.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Making request");
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Alternatively, Replace `foo`, `useEffect` and add requestId

```
 const [requestId, setRequestId] = useState(0);

 const foo = async () => {
    getScreen(match.params.id);
    setTimeout(setRequestId(requestId+1), 3000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    foo();
    setNodeupdated(screen.data)
  }, [requestId]);
```

Comment: console.log(screen) is still at initial state

Comment: Similar to before hook code, you can call `setNodeupdated(screen.data)` just after the getScreen right?

Comment: Can you also try with second argument to [screen]?

Comment: After 3 seconds it just errors - Cannot read property... of undefined

Comment: Oh I see. @Daniel, Can you try the alternate way as I just updated answer?